# Can't upgrade to 15.04 from 14.10

Tags: updates, 15.04

I can't upgrade to 15.04 from 14.10. I am getting this error when building software channels:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/dists/vivid/restricted/source/Sources
Bad header line [IP: 77.75.110.242 80]
```

Comment: What happens when you fix the "bad header"?

Comment: You have to disable all 3rd party reposiories and if one repository is failing, use another - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file.

Delete the contents.

Paste the following:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Hi tried what you said but get this error amos@DEEPTHOUGHT:~$ sudo  

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libavcodec54 libavfilter3 libavformat54 libavresample1 libopenjpeg2
  libproxy-tools libsvga1 libswscale2 libvlc5 libvlccore8 vlc-data
  wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 14 to remove and 1623 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 141 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Abort.
root@DEEPTHOUGHT:~#